# Is there any feature or setting can show compile error in parent directory in intellij-idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a multi-module maven project, like this:

```
project A
|-project B
  |-project C
```

If there is a compile error in module C, and I collapse module B, I can't see the error.
Is there any feature or setting can show compile error in parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but in your situation I thought Idea would show a little red squiggly in the collapsed project B even before running a compile. You should see the error immediately as Idea builds it AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) and it should remain visible through all parent projects. In my version (I'm running 12 ultimate but I believe the feature has been there since multi-modules were 1st introduced) If I have all projects collapsed I would see the squiggly on the main leaf. I then open the leaf and it will show the squiggly on the sub module that has the error. (This assumes you use the module grouping feature which allows you to build and fold groups into one another. If you're not using grouping then your errant module will be visible at the root of the project module list.)